# How to fetch metadata for all tables created for particular user in oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I have a user in oracle 11g named testUser. Now I have 4 tables under the user testUser. I want to fetch metadata only for all the tables that are existing under user testUser.
I am using getTables method provided in interface java.sql.DatabaseMetaData. The signature of method looks like:

```
getTables(java.lang.String catalog,
java.lang.String schemaPattern,
java.lang.String tableNamePattern,
java.lang.String[] types);
```

Can anyone please help me in understanding the value that should be passed in the first and second argument of the getTables method.
I think in third argument tableNamePattern, I have to pass "%" and in fourth argument I will pass string array with only one element "TABLE" as I have to fetch tables.

I am not sure about the first and second argument value. if I am passing null in the first and second argument, It tries to fetch all the tables of all the users existing in oracle. But I want to fecth tables created under single user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may pass null for the first argument and username (TESTUSER - upper case is important) for the second. Catalog is not matter for Oracle database, schemaPattern (name) and username is the same in Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

According to oracle docs:
 **getTables**

```
ResultSet getTables(String catalog,
                    String schemaPattern,
                    String tableNamePattern,
                    String[] types)
                    throws SQLException

Retrieves a description of the tables available in the given catalog. Only table descriptions matching the catalog, schema, table name and type criteria are returned. They are ordered by TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_CAT, TABLE_SCHEM and TABLE_NAME.

Each table description has the following columns:

    TABLE_CAT String => table catalog (may be null)
    TABLE_SCHEM String => table schema (may be null)
    TABLE_NAME String => table name
    TABLE_TYPE String => table type. Typical types are "TABLE", "VIEW", "SYSTEM TABLE", "GLOBAL TEMPORARY", "LOCAL TEMPORARY", "ALIAS", "SYNONYM".
    REMARKS String => explanatory comment on the table
    TYPE_CAT String => the types catalog (may be null)
    TYPE_SCHEM String => the types schema (may be null)
    TYPE_NAME String => type name (may be null)
    SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME String => name of the designated "identifier" column of a typed table (may be null)
    REF_GENERATION String => specifies how values in SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME are created. Values are "SYSTEM", "USER", "DERIVED". (may be null) 

Note: Some databases may not return information for all tables.

Parameters:
    catalog - a catalog name; must match the catalog name as it is stored in the database; "" retrieves those without a catalog; null means that the catalog name should not be used to narrow the search
    schemaPattern - a schema name pattern; must match the schema name as it is stored in the database; "" retrieves those without a schema; null means that the schema name should not be used to narrow the search
    tableNamePattern - a table name pattern; must match the table name as it is stored in the database
    types - a list of table types, which must be from the list of table types returned from getTableTypes(),to include; null returns all types 
Returns:
    ResultSet - each row is a table description
```

To cut it short

1. The first parameter `catalog` is nothing but server instance
2. The second parameter `schema` is nothing but namespace within database, identical to user account